# How to validate textbox in C# WF?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have two text boxes in windows form.
Also one disabled button.

How I can do validation text box:

- if field is empty then disable button
- if value inside field is less then 5 then disable button
- other case - enable button

I tried this on event TextChange, but when I tried to enter value `43` I get notification, because event `TextChange` works after each typing symbols.

Code:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            {
                button6.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried?

Comment: In webforms you need to do it manually, can you use WPF? It's easier then with MVVM pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your event handle like this :

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button6.Enabled = 
        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) && textBox2.Text.Length > 5
}
```

As for disabling the button on start up, you just set button6 to be disabled by default.

Or, invoke your validation in your constructor :

```
textBox2_TextChanged(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to validate each time a key is pressed but would rather validate when the user leaves the field, instead of hooking into the `TextChanged` event, hook into the `Leave` event.

```
private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button6.Enabled = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)) && textBox2.Text.Length >= 5;

    if (!button6.Enabled)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how I can save focus on current field if validation is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Neither `TextChanged` nor `Leave` events are appropriate for this. The proper event is called (surprise:-) `Validating`. You need to set `e.Cancel = true` if validation is wrong. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx